# char array input with space

Tags: c, operating-system

my program works fine if i give hard code value to char *w="ls -l" but i am trying to take input form user not working help my code:: using input error occur 
i don't understand the concept of fgets using fgets its gives the garbig value to execv

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

void func(char **arr, char *w)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    char temp[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] == '')
        {
            arr[k] = temp;
            arr[k+1] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        if (w[i] == ' ')
        {
            arr[k] = temp;
            k++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[j] = w[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
}
int main()
{
    char *n = "/bin/ls";
    char *arr[10] = {''};
    char p[100] = {''};
    char *w = "ls -l";
    int i = 0;
    //printf("bilal-hassan-qadri $ >>");
    //fgets(p, 100, stdin);
    arr[2] = NULL;
    bool found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(w); i++)
    {
        if (w[i] == ' ')
        {
            found=true;
            func(arr,w);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
      arr[0] = w;
    int status;
    int id = fork();
    if (id == 0)
    {
        if (execv(n,arr) < 0)
        {
            printf("invalid commandn");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ninvalid command");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `fgets` is giving you trouble, you probably need to [remove the newline](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/3386109)

Comment: `if (execv(n,arr) < 0) printf("invalid commandn"); else printf("ninvalid command");` - this is a bit weird to be honest.

Comment: any solution to handle the space and null

Comment: What do you want to do with `w[i] == ''`? It won't compile with gcc saying `error: empty character constant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the function `func`, You have to copy the string to elements of `arr`
  instead of just passing the address of `temp`, which will vanish on leaving the function.
  You can use `strdup` instead of `copy_string` if your system supports it.
- You have to terminate the string in `temp` before copying it.
- Empty string constant `''` seems invalid. You shouldn't use it.
- `fgets` stores new-line character `\n` if it exists. Check for it and remove if it isn't wanted.

Fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

char *copy_string(const char *str) {
    char *s = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (s) strcpy(s, str); else {perror("malloc"); exit(1);}
    return s;
}

void func(char **arr, char *w)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    char temp[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] == '\0' || w[i] == '\n')
        {
            temp[j] = '\0';
            arr[k] = copy_string(temp);
            arr[k+1] = NULL;
            break;
        }
        if (w[i] == ' ')
        {
            temp[j] = '\0';
            arr[k] = copy_string(temp);
            k++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            temp[j] = w[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
}
int main(void)
{
    char *n = "/bin/ls";
    char *arr[10] = {NULL};
    char p[100] = {0};
    char *w = "ls -l";
    int i = 0;
    //printf("bilal-hassan-qadri $ >>");
    fgets(p, 100, stdin);
    w = p;
    arr[2] = NULL;
    bool found = false;
    for (i = 0; w[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (w[i] == ' ')
        {
            found=true;
            func(arr,w);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
      arr[0] = w;
    int status;
    int id = fork();
    if (id == 0)
    {
        if (execv(n,arr) < 0)
        {
            printf("invalid commandn");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ninvalid command");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&status);
        for (i = 0; arr[i] != NULL; i++) free(arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```